# cannot access ServiceManager in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2, servicemanager

I'm on 2.0.4.

My files:

https://gist.github.com/4191490

According to the documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

If a class implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface, then its object will be initialized with the service manager. I did the same (see BaseEntity.php in my source code). However, the service manager was never initialised and is thus unavailable from the subclass Snippet.

Question: How to retrieve the global or module's ServireManager instance, so that I can access other services? (Most of them are singleton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` to work as suggested the instance needs to come out of the `ServiceManager`. This is because there is an Initalizer attached to the `ServiceManager` that injects the ServiceManager if that interface is found (You can see this in - `Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig`).

You could add your classes to the SevriceManager configuration and then pull them through your `$sm` instance or even modify your getTableGateway to add the following:

```
if ($prototype instanceof ServiceManagerAwareInterface)
{
    $prototype->setServiceManager($sm);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ServiceManagerAwareInterface` is deprecated and is not aoutoinjected
use `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` instead

Comment: actually ServiceManagerAwareInterface is the one in use, as the ServiceManager is passed to the factory methods in Module.php, not ServiceLocator. problem was that ServiceManagerAwareInterface is not initialized automatically, so I ended up initialized all instances manually, as DrBeza suggested.

Comment: ACTUALLY ServiceManagerAwareInterface is deprecated. Use ServiceLocatorAwareInterface instead, because ServiceManager is concrete ServiceLocator